# Reliable persisted sidekiq task

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

I am working on a ruby application that creates todos and meetings.

There will be reminders that are sent out with respect to each meeting or todo as you would imagine.

We are already using sidekiq and it would be nice to use sidekiq to create the scheduled jobs in x number of days/hours etc.

My concern is that we will lose the jobs if redis restarts.

Am I write in assuming that if redis restarts, we lose the jobs and if so, is there anything that can be done about it?

If not sidekiq, what else could I use?

Comment: Did you ever get a workaround to this problem? I have the same situation. Please help with what did you figure out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing that, just go through the link http://redis.io/topics/persistence. `Snapshotting` is a technique to snapshots of the dataset on disk.

Answer (score 0):

Since Sidekiq is built on top of Redis, you can set `redis` to snapshot your data with the `--save` flag.

```
docker run --name some-redis -d redis redis-server --save 60 1 --loglevel warning
```

In this example, `--save 60 1` will save a snapshot of the DB every `60 seconds` **if at least** `1 write` operation was performed. If you are not frequently restarting your `redis` instance, this is probably good enough for many use cases. For all of the details on redis persistence, see:

https://redis.io/docs/management/persistence/

If you have a deployment job that you know is going to restart `redis`, for example, to load a new kernel, you could run: `redis-cli SAVE && reboot` to dump memory to disk before restarting (thus not have to worry about waiting for the 60 second timer to run out).

That said, for your particular example about meeting notifications, I would probably use mysql galera replication and a cron or redis job to scan the database looking for notes that are ready for email sending, rather than relying on redis which may periodically be restarting, unless your users are OK with every great once in a while, email not showing up that could have otherwise been delivered.